# Why would Datak Tarr wear sunglasses?

Tags: defiance

In the TV show [Defiance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defiance_(TV_series)), one of the characters, Datak Tarr, is an alien living on Earth.

Now, this may sound silly and I am aware that the most likely reason for both things is *The Rule of Cool*, but I could not help noticing them.

Scenes set in the interior of Datak's house show it in very bright white tones:

[image]

I interpreted the design of his house is an indication of how his species' homeworld looks like, as it would stand to reason that they would prefer to live in similar surroundings as on their home planet.

However, another scene shows him wearing sunglasses:

[image]

If the environment he feels comfortable in is so brightly lit, shouldn't Earth's natural light be already too dark for him - so dark that the extra darkening from the sunglasses would block his vision entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Judging from the lighting conditions and the extremely white, reflective surfaces in the [Castithan](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Castithan) homes, bright light is probably not an issue for the average Castithan. So the reason Datak Tarr is wearing sunglasses is more likely social rather than protective.**

> Datak Tarr is the primary figure in Defiance's underworld, running everything from gambling to weapons smuggling and organized crime. True to his Castithan ways, Datak is always on the lookout for opportunities that allow him to get his hooks into people so he can later manipulate them to his own ends. Born into a lower caste on his homeworld, Datak was a survivor who found his way onto an Ark despite his low standing. **TVTropes.com -> Main Characters -> [Datak Tarr](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/Defiance)**

- As a member of the council, Datak wants to appear to fit in rather than stand out. As such, sunglasses, even if he doesn't need them can give him a cosmopolitan air, definitely an asset among humans, even if the rest of the Votan are unimpressed with them.
- Datak Tarr, as a Castithan versed in the ways of intimidation, is learning to use more subtle means of getting what he wants. Tarr knows his appearance, particularly his penetrating stare, is effective at frightening people, but as a Council member he needs to be more approachable. Hence the glasses. It gives him a gentle barrier between him and potential constituents while he composes himself and removes them to continue conversation.
- Datak Tarr is a crafty fellow and has learned the value of appearances. His affectation as a kinder, gentler statesman is just one more face he is learning to wear to get what he wants. Wearing sunglasses when no one else in his culture does, is just another way for him to emphasis his unique nature; a man capable for speaking for all of the [Votan](http://en.defiance-wiki.com/wiki/Votan).

[image: Datak Tarr]

*Can someone get Datak some shades, his stare is starting to creep me out.*